# Trying to overwrite a string that has single quotes using Perl or sed in the terminal

Tags: sed, terminal

I have the following line in a file:

```
$app-assets:"/assets/";
```

I am trying to use sed in the terminal to overwrite that line to read as follows:

```
$app-assets:"http://www.example.com/assets/";
```

I have tried the following but it does not work:

```
sed -i \'\' -e \'s/app-assets:"/assets/"/app-assets:"http://www.example.com/assets/"/g\' myfile.txt
```

I am fine using Perl if easier.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
sed 's/app-assets:\"\/assets\/\";/app-assets:\"http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/assets\/\";/g' filename
```

Comment: just habit. (from all possible variants, idk why but i like use slash, and yeah escape all other slash characters)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following ***sed*** approach:

```
sed -i 's~\(\$app-assets:"\)\(/assets/\)"~\1http://www.example.com\2"~' myfile.txt
```

---

- `~` here is treated as *sed* subcommand separator